# Словоформа: "он", "она", "они"

Tags: грамматика, словообразование, морфология, местоимения

Скажите, пожалуйста, айтишнику. Слова "он", "она", "они" — это разные словоформы одного слова или же отдельные слова?

Answer (score 3):

Местоимение 3-го лица "он" указывает на того/то, о ком/чем идет речь, но не на говорящего или его собеседника.

Местоимение "он" имеет морфологическую категорию рода, выраженную тремя рядами падежных форм: он, она, оно.

Местоимение "он" характеризуется наличием категории числа, выраженной противопоставлением форм ед. и мн. числа: он, она, оно и они.

Из этого следует, что "он", "она", "оно", "они" это разные словоформы одного слова "он".

Можно добавить, что местоимения я, мы, ты, вы - это разные слова, они имеют только падежные формы.

Answer (score 0):

Это разные слова, а не словоформы. Каждое из русских местоимений (я, ты, он, она, оно, мы, вы, они) является словом, имеющим свои словоформы. Например, словоформы слова ОН: его, ему, ним, нём. Многие ошибаются, думая что местоимение ОН может поменять род и стать словом ОНА. Нет, ОН и ОНА это разные слова (как СОСЕД и СОСЕДКА), а не формы одного слова.